# Parentheses around foreach in Powershell

Tags: powershell

For context, I'm trying to run multiple powershell commands in a single line of code so that I can use it in a Dockerfile.

```
($SubInterfaceInfo = netsh interface ipv4 show subinterface) -and ($vEthernetInterfaces = (($SubInterfaceInfo | Where-Object { $_ -match 'vEthernet' }) -split '\s\s')[-1]) -and (foreach($vEthernetInterface in $vEthernetInterfaces){ netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface $vEthernetInterface mtu=1460 })
```

When run, I get the error:

```
Unexpected token 'in' in expression or statement.
```

Individually all of these commands work, however, the parentheses around the foreach seems to be the cause of the problem.

This command works:

```
foreach($vEthernetInterface in $vEthernetInterfaces){ netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface $vEthernetInterface mtu=1460 }
```

But this causes the error:

```
(foreach($vEthernetInterface in $vEthernetInterfaces){ netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface $vEthernetInterface mtu=1460 })
```

Is a way I can make the foreach command work inside the parentheses, or another way of using the `foreach` loop with `-and`?

Comment: Why not join them with semicolons?  `command1; command2; command3`

Comment: You might also use the [foreach method](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2015/12/10/foreach-method-in-powershell.aspx): `$vEthernetInterfaces.foreach{ netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface $_ mtu=1460 }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grouping operator, `(...)`, is primarily meant for constructing *nested pipelines*, and you must therefore provide a valid pipeline expression (eg. call a cmdlet, evaluate a variable expression, etc.) as the first statement.

To nest control flow expressions like the `foreach` loop, use the subexpression operator `$(...)`:

```
$(foreach($vEthernetInterface in $vEthernetInterfaces){ netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface $vEthernetInterface mtu=1460 })
```